# The shorter the message, the larger the prize

Tags: combinatorics, optimization

Andrei and Belle have been set a task by their “friend”, Carroll.  Carroll has promised them money depending on how well they do.

Carroll will give a 99 bit array to Andrei and a different one to Belle. They don’t see each other’s arrays. Andrei gets to send one message (made up of bits) to Belle and Belle then has to say whether she has no bits the  same as Andrei’s in common positions or alternatively if exactly 99/3=33 of the bits in her array are the same as the bits in the corresponding position in Andrei’s array.

Carroll has promised that either one of those two conditions will be true.

To give an example with 3 bit arrays, if Andrei gets 011 and Belle gets 101 they have exactly 3/3=1 of their bits in common and 2 distinct.  If Belle had received 100 then the two arrays are entirely distinct. Following Carroll’s rule, she could not have received 111 for example.

Clearly Andrei can just send his entire array to Belle. But here is the twist. Carroll will give them $(99-message length)*100 so that shorter messages get more money.  She sets out the rules as follows:

- Andrei and Belle can talk only before they receive their arrays from Carroll.
- Whatever scheme they come up must **always** allow Belle to give the right answer no matter what arrays Carroll gives them. Belle’s decision on what to output must only depend on the message she gets from Andrei and her own array of bits.

How much money can they make?

Comment: I had to read fljx’s answer through three times before I could make any sense of it, because there’s a fundamental issue that’s not clear from the question. I understood the puzzle as Andrei having to send _a specific subset of bits from his array_ to Belle (positions 11, 36 and 72, corresponding to [1, 0, 1] for example), and she would then have to tell whether she had 33/99 or 0/99 bits in common in her array, but fljx’s answer makes no sense under that interpretation. Is the message Andrei sends in fact allowed to contain **any data at all in bit format**?

Comment: Also, your use of ‘message’ is confusing. You appear to be using it both to refer to the arrays they get from Carroll and the message sent from Andrei to Belle. I assume you mean that Andrei and Belle can talk only before they receive their _arrays from Carroll_?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thank you for the fix. Yes Andrei sends any data he wants to Belle. I am just measuring the size of the message in bits.

Comment: `Carroll will give a 99 bit array to Andrei and a possibly different one to Belle` - the next sentence makes it apparent that it's not just possible, it' certain, that the array would be different, may be just omit the word "possibly"?

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh I don't fully understand. It is possible for Andrei and Belle to get exactly the same array of bits

Comment: @Simd Oh I probably misread this then but I cannot see how. I thought that the puzzle say they are only two possibilities: either all of the bits different or 66 of them. That would preclude all the bits and then the arrays being the same. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh I see what you mean and you are right!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Andrei can send a message that is:

> **One** bit long.
>  And they will get **$9800** from Carroll

How?

> Consider the two messages together.
>
>  If they are entirely different there will be exactly ninety nine 1's across both messages, so the combined parity will be odd.
>
>  If they have thirty three bits in common, those alike bits will contain an even number of 1's, and the unalike bits will have sixty six 1's across both messages. So the combined parity will be even.
>
>  So all Andrei has to do is send the parity of their message to Belle.

Comment: I am just checking, if we change 99 to 90 and 33 to 30, can your approach still apply?

Comment: @Simd if the message length is even, the parity solution no longer works. Not sure what the optimal solution would be in that case.

Comment: You cracked this very quickly!

Comment: Shouldn't the last "their" not be "his" (since he has no access to Belle's info)

Comment: @JasonSmith "their" is singular in this case (meaning Andrei's). I was using gender-neutral language, as Andrei isn't a name I'm familiar with. Re-reading the question now I see there is one "his" that I didn't notice when I answered, so I could have used "his".

Comment: @fljx "their" is confusing as it suggests pural. If unsure about gender rather use "his/her" in order not to make it confusing. Tip: if unsure about gender: enter the name in Google and search images. It then quickly becomes clear.

Comment: Or just use gender-neutral language and skip all that.

Comment: @JasonSmith "their" as a gender neutral third person singular is pretty well established now and avoids a whole bunch of additional headaches. Using his/her is backward step. Using Google is a non-starter. Try getting it to reliably tell you what gender Bobby, or Carol, or Nicola should be (for example), when you have no idea what the cultural background of the question setter is.