# The shorter the message, the larger the prize (version II)

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, optimization

This is a successor question to [The shorter the message, the larger the prize](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/121574/8998) .  For completeness I will include the entire question even though only the numbers have changed. Solutions to this puzzle will be very different to solutions to the previous one.

Andrei and Belle have been set a task by their “friend”, Carroll.  Carroll has promised them money depending on how well they do.

Carroll will give a 90 bit array to Andrei and a different one to Belle. They don’t see each other’s arrays. Andrei gets to send one message (made up of bits) to Belle and Belle then has to say whether she has no bits the  same as Andrei’s in common positions or alternatively if exactly 90/3=30 of the bits in her array are the same as the bits in the corresponding position in Andrei’s array.

Carroll has promised that either one of those two conditions will be true.

To give an example with 3 bit arrays, if Andrei gets 011 and Belle gets 101 they have exactly 3/3=1 of their bits in common and 2 distinct.  If Belle had received 100 then the two arrays are entirely distinct. Following Carroll’s rule, she could not have received 111 for example.

Clearly Andrei can just send his entire array to Belle. But here is the twist. Carroll will give them $(90-message length)*100 so that shorter messages get more money.  She sets out the rules as follows:

- Andrei and Belle can talk only before they receive their arrays from Carroll.
- Whatever scheme they come up must **always** allow Belle to give the right answer no matter what arrays Carroll gives them. Belle’s decision on what to output must only depend on the message she gets from Andrei and her own array of bits.

How much money can they make?

Comment: Hey @Simd, do you know the optimal solution?

Comment: @user1502040 Yes, although I don't have a proof it is optimal.

Comment: @Simd, would you mind adding another bounty? It would be nice to have people working on it, like, not at a snail's pace.

Comment: @newQOpenWid would be more than happy to. But who do I give this bounty to??

Comment: @tehtmi's answer is easily the most detailed and helpful (xnor's answer is just an extension imo) and technically has the optimal solution currently because he gives his own improvement to user1502040's answer.

Comment: @newQOpenWid True.  The problem is that everyone has contributed a lot. I'll give it to tehtmi and I hope it doesn't annoy anyone.

Comment: Simd, what was the message length that you had when you posted this? Is it better than 44 bits?

Comment: @isaacg It was 44.

Answer (score 13):

I will give a very weak lower bound (improved based on [xnor's idea](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/121706/30964)), and a minor improvement to [user1502040's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/121586/30964).

Lower bound:

> Andrei needs to send a message with at least $\log_2(38)$ bits of information (rounding up to 6 bits).

Proof:

> The puzzle reduces to finding ($\log_2$ of) the chromatic number of a certain graph. For simplicity, pretend that Andrei's bit string is the complement of what is given in the question's formulation, so it is either identical to Belle's, or differs by 30 bits.
>
>
>  Let $f$ be the function that Andrei uses to generate his message from his secret bit string. Suppose Belle has bit string $x$. If she receives message $f(x)$, she must conclude that Andrei's string is also $x$. Andrei must have either $x$ or a string that differs from $x$ by 30 bits. If there is a string $y$ that differs from $x$ by 30 bits and $f(x) = f(y)$, then Belle will not be able to distinguish these cases. So, any two bit strings $x$ and $y$ that differ by 30 bits must have $f(x) \neq f(y)$.
>
>
>  This condition is also sufficient. If Belle has bit string $x$ and sees $f(x)$, she concludes that Andrei also has $x$. Otherwise, Andrei has $y$ which differs by 30 bits and $f(x) \neq f(y)$ so Belle concludes Andrei doesn't have $x$.
>
>
>  We can consider the graph where vertices are bit strings of length 90 and there are edges between strings that differ by 30 bits. (This is the distance-30 graph of the 90-dimensional hypercube graph.) If we color the vertices of this graph so that any pair of vertices joined by an edge have different colors, then Andrei can take $f(x)$ to be (a bit string encoding) the color of $x$ in this coloring. Thus, the number of bits Andrei needs is the $\log_2$ of the chromatic number of this graph.

> There is a clique of size $38$ in this graph. The difference between any two of the bit strings below is 30 bits. Therefore, each must have a different color, so there are at least 38 colors in any valid coloring of the graph. (Following the convention of xnor, blank spaces are 0's.)

```
11111111111111111111                                             
11111               111111111111111                              
11111                              111111111111111               
11111                                             111111111111111
     11111          11111          11111          11111          
     11111               11111          11111          11111     
     11111                    11111          11111          11111
          11111     11111               11111               11111
          11111          11111               1111111111          
          11111               1111111111               11111     
               1111111111                    11111     11111     
               11111     11111     11111                    11111
               11111          11111     11111     11111          
1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    
 1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1   1    1    1    
  1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1  1    1    1    
   1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1 1    1    1    
    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    11    1    1    
1    1    1     1    1    1     1    1    1     1    1    1     1    1    1 1    1    1   
 1    1    1     1    1    1     1    1    1     1    1    11    1    1     1    1    1   
  1    1    1     1    1    1     1    1    11    1    1     1    1    1    1    1    1   
   1    1    1     1    1    11    1    1     1    1    1     1    1    1   1    1    1   
    1    1    11    1    1     1    1    1     1    1    1     1    1    1  1    1    1   
1    1    1      1    1    1      1    1    1 1    1    1      1    1    1   1    1    1  
 1    1    1      1    1    1 1    1    1      1    1    1      1    1    1  1    1    1  
  1    1    1      1    1    1 1    1    1      1    1    1 1    1    1      1    1    1  
   1    1    1 1    1    1      1    1    1      1    1    1 1    1    1     1    1    1  
    1    1    1 1    1    1      1    1    1 1    1    1      1    1    1    1    1    1  
1    1    1       1    1    1  1    1    1       1    1    1  1    1    1     1    1    1 
 1    1    1       1    1    1  1    1    1  1    1    1       1    1    1    1    1    1 
  1    1    1  1    1    1       1    1    1  1    1    1       1    1    1   1    1    1 
   1    1    1  1    1    1       1    1    1  1    1    1  1    1    1       1    1    1 
    1    1    1  1    1    1  1    1    1       1    1    1  1    1    1      1    1    1 
1    1    1        1    1    1   1    1    1   1    1    1   1    1    1       1    1    1
 1    1    1   1    1    1        1    1    1   1    1    1   1    1    1      1    1    1
  1    1    1   1    1    1   1    1    1        1    1    1   1    1    1     1    1    1
   1    1    1   1    1    1   1    1    1   1    1    1        1    1    1    1    1    1
    1    1    1   1    1    1   1    1    1   1    1    1   1    1    1        1    1    1
```

> The first 13 elements of the clique are just  [xnor's idea of using a finite projective plane](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/121706/30964). One way of understanding the additional 25 elements is to think of them as strings of base 5 digits. If the strings are broken up into blocks of 15 bits, the only blocks are `100001000010000`, and the four rotations of this string which we will map to the digits $0$ through $4$. Thus if two of our 6-digit base 5 strings have digit of the same value in the same position, they have 3 overlapping 1's in the binary, and if they have don't have a matching digit in a position, it will contribute 6 to the difference from the three non-overlapping 1's in each string. Thus, there will be a difference of 30 bits whenever there is exactly one base 5 digit that matches in position and value. Furthermore, in the binary, each string has exactly one 1 bit in each block of 5 for 18 total 1's, four of which will overlap with any projective plane bit string (as these use the same blocks of 5 bits) which also gives a difference of 30 (four bits of difference contributed from each of four blocks where the projective string has 1's and one bit of difference from each other block: $4 \cdot 4 + 14 = 30$).
>
>
>  We can construct a set of 25 of these 6-digit base 5 strings such that every pair has exactly one digit that matches in both value and position. For every value/position combination, there can be at most 5 strings that share it, as a sixth string would have to match one of the others in a second position. Thus, each position can account for $5 {5 \choose 2} = 50$ pairs, and all six positions account for all ${25 \choose 2} = 300 = 6 \cdot 50$ pairs.
>
>
>   These strings can be constructed as follows: We will give each string a coordinate $(x, y)$ with each of $x$ and $y$ ranging from $0$ to $4$. Let $p$ indicate the index of a position in the string from $0$ to $4$. Then we choose the digit at $(x, y, p)$ to be $y+xp \bmod 5$. Thus, for any pair $(x, y)$ and $(x', y')$ with $x \neq x'$, there is a unique solution to $y+xp = y'+x'p$ given by $p=(y-y')/(x'-x)$. If $x = x'$, there is no solution (except pairing a string with itself), so we can just take the last digit to be $x$. The strings looks like this:

```
(0, 0): 000000
(0, 1): 111110
(0, 2): 222220
(0, 3): 333330
(0, 4): 444440
(1, 0): 012341
(1, 1): 123401
(1, 2): 234011
(1, 3): 340121
(1, 4): 401231
(2, 0): 024132
(2, 1): 130242
(2, 2): 241302
(2, 3): 302412
(2, 4): 413022
(3, 0): 031423
(3, 1): 142033
(3, 2): 203143
(3, 3): 314203
(3, 4): 420313
(4, 0): 043214
(4, 1): 104324
(4, 2): 210434
(4, 3): 321044
(4, 4): 432104
```

Further comments about this construction, cliques, and possible generalizations:

> In general, different projective planes could be used. We perhaps don't need all the conditions of a projective plane, though. If we say graph points are plane points, we need exactly one line between every pair of points (ie every pair of points has the same size bit overlap), and every point needs to be incident to the same number of lines. But, we don't really need any condition on lines. A projective plane is still generally best because if all points are incident to $n + 1$ lines, and any line is incident to $n + 1$ points, the you can't have any line incident to more than $n + 1$ points (except having every point be collinear which may actually be useful in some generalizations) and having every line incident to $n + 1$ points gives the most points -- and this is a projective plane. But, a subset of a projective plane can be useful. For example, although xnor notes that the projective plane of order 5 doesn't quite fit (when tripled to meet the distance 30 condition), if we leave off one line and all the incident points, we can fit 25 points and 30 lines in 90 bits. (But, I don't know how to turn this into a bigger clique as it seems harder to extend.)
>
>
>  There are multiple ways to extend a projective plane clique. To have the same overlap with each projective plane element, one must have the same number of 1's in each block of the projective plane. For the plane used in this answer, that can be 0, 1, or 2. This answer uses 1, and xnor's uses 0. 2 also seems interesting, but it is maybe hampered because, the way the numbers work out, it can't use any additional bits.
>
>
>  For the base 5 construction, the same basic construction should work in any finite field (in other words if the base is a power of a prime, although finite fields of non-prime order aren't just the integers modulo the order of the field). I'm not sure what the best you can do is for other bases. Larger bases also need more bits to encode each digit. And, the number of non-matching digits (equal to the base) has to divide the distance. Most digit encodings will give an even contribution to distance, so in practice, the number of non-matching digits has to divide half the distance. (The only exception to an even-distance encoding is to encode a binary digit as a odd-length string or its complement.) Finding a digit encoding is the problem of again finding a clique of size equal to the base on some smaller number of bits with a smaller distance. (We may impose another restriction, like compatibility with a projective plane, but we don't necessarily need to do this. For example, the base 5 configuration can be encoded in fewer bits using a projective plane, but there seems to be no advantage to doing this because it breaks compatibility with the projective plane used for the additional clique elements.)
>
>
>  So, for the case of 30, the next higher divisor of 15 is 15 itself. Even if there was a good base 15 configuration, there's no way of encoding 16 base-15 digits (with the desired distance condition) in 90 bits.
>
>
>  Another option rather than using a divisor of the distance is to decompose the distance as a sum. One could find two cliques with distances that sum to the desired distance, and then pair elements of the cliques (with extra elements of the larger clique going to waste). 30 could be solved with a base 7 and a base 8 configuration each with digits contributing 2 each. This would give a clique of size 49, but I don't know how to encode it in fewer than 128 bits (7 bits for each base 7 digit and 8 bits for each base 8 digit). (For distance 2 digits, the shortest encoding I know is generally just to take the strings with a single 1. The only exception is perhaps base 4 which has `000`, `011`, `101`, `110` as a 3-bit encoding.)
>
>
>  In general, using either technique seems to be a simplification to the question of finding a clique. In both cases, we are looking at overlap of a single digit. It is possible the only advantage of doing so is in managing complexity. Overlap of multiple digits could admit a larger clique, but then maybe finding a clique itself is already this kind of problem. And, of course, the chromatic number of the graph may be larger than the size of the largest clique anyway.
>
>
>  Also, note that it we take any two bit strings and take their bitwise-exlusive-or with some fixed string, the distance between the resulting strings is the same as the distance between the original strings. So, we could take the bitwise-exlusive-or of every member of a clique with one of its members to transform it into a clique containing the string of all zeroes and where every other string has 30 1's which must overlap with exactly 15 1's of each other member.

[User1502040's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/121586/30964) can be improved to

> 44 bits

by the following method:

> Observe that $f(x)$ and the bitwise complement of $f(x)$ are never adjacent since it would take at least a 44 bit change to invert the 44 bits of row parity information. If two colors are never adjacent, they can be merged into the same color. This halves the number of colors, saving one bit of information.
>
>
>  One way of making this concrete is to have Andrei follow the original procedure, then if the first row's parity is $1$, take the complement of the entire message. Don't send the parity of the first row (which is now $0$ either way).
>
>
>  The resulting coloring is at least locally optimal in the sense that every color is adjacent to every other color (and in fact every node is adjacent to every other color), but this seems to be quite a weak statement in general. (Very poor colorings can be "optimal" in this way.)

Further comments about this strategy and possible generalizations:

> Taking the parity of a group of size 2 is powerful because if the parity matches there are only two possibilities: either there is a perfect match, or both bits have been flipped. If we try to take the parity of a larger group, there are more kinds of changes that can go undetected. This can create problems. For example, with at least three groups of size three or more, even if we know the parity of all the columns and even if we know the exact number of 1's in the string, we can't distinguish `(110)(101)(011)` from `(101)(011)(110)`. These have a difference of 6. Since `(10)(01)` and `(01)(10)` also can't be distinguished, generally, any even error larger than size 2 can go undetected. Even with groups of size 2, we can't detect an error that's size is a multiple of 4 (at least, not without additional information).
>
>
>  We can fix this problem by taking more than one bit of information from a group. For example, by pairing each group configuration with its complement (e.g. by taking the complement if the first bit is $1$, then don't send the first bit of the group which is now $0$ either way), we get the same power as taking the parity of a group of size 2 (and saving one bit from sending the whole group): if this checksum matches, then the group is either identical or exactly the complement. Thus, if we split a string into groups of size 3 and all group checksums match, then either the strings match, or the number of errors is a multiple of 3. This isn't so useful for 30 errors, but it would immediately resolve the question whenever the number of errors isn't a multiple of 3. (It doesn't beat [isaacg's approach](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/121579/30964) if the number of errors is a third of the string length, but it is better if the number of errors is smaller.) If the number of errors is a multiple of 3, we would know the number of errors in any column is the quotient. In principle this is useful, and it is the information we use when dividing by 2 using groups of 2. In such cases we have to recurse, and that is most powerful when the quotient is odd, since that case can be solved in one bit.
>
>
>  In applying the optimization original to this answer (pairing up colors that are never adjacent), depending on the number of groups versus the size of the error, it might not be possible to do the optimization at all (if the number of errors is greater than or equal to number of groups for which information is being sent), or it might be possible to find larger sets of colors that can be merged. (I don't think it is possible to merge three or more colors in the example at hand.)
>
>
>  Also note that this message function is linear if we treat the bit strings as vectors over the finite field of order 2. Also (as noted above), the distance between two strings is preserved if we add the same vector to both. (Adding here is the same as taking the bitwise-exclusive-or of two bit strings.) This seems to be a favorable property. Given $x$ and $y$, then $f(x) = f(y)$ iff $f(0) = f(x+x)=f(x)+f(x)=f(x)+f(y)=f(x+y)$; and $0$ and $x+y$ are adjacent iff $x$ and $y$ are adjacent. Thus, linearity seems to give us a lot of what we want from symmetry (we only need to consider cases involving $0$ (or some other fixed element)). ([The answer from isaacg](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/121579/30964) is also linear.)

Comment: I love your formulation as a graph problem. Now I am wondering if this can be computed exactly if we have 6 bit arrays instead of 90 bit arrays. That is just to get a feeling for a simple case.

Comment: In fact I am guessing integer programming can solve this for small cases?

Comment: @Simd The optimal solutions for 3, 6, and 9 are 1, 3, and 1 bit(s).

Comment: @user1502040 How did you work out the answer for 6?

Comment: @Simd by graph coloring

Comment: @user1502040  which solver did you use?

Comment: @2012rcampion. Of course, Belle looks at both her string and the message, otherwise she can't give an answer even if $f$ is the identity. But, Belle needs to reason about what Andrei would have done for each possible string he received, and that means using his function. Belle having a function isn't part of my framing. But, for example if Belle answers that the strings are equal iff $g(x, m)=m$ then $g(x, m) = m$ implies Andrei has $x$ so $f(x) = m$ so $g(x, m) = f(x)$.

Comment: @2012rcampion In my answer, there is no $g$, there is an $f$. Belle is just using logic, and $f$ has to have certain properties to allow her to use logic successfully. If $f$ has those properties, she has a strategy by using $f$. Because we know $f$ must have these properties, Belle can always use this strategy. Belle behaves identically in any correct strategy, so any correct strategy must be equivalent to this. In other words, for example, if Belle and Andrei both have $x$, Belle will get message $f(x)$, so Belle having $x$ and getting $f(x)$ must mean Belle says the strings are equal.

Comment: @2012rcampion Also, since your were asking about the lower bound, I will mention that the bound only depends on the condition on $f$. If $f$ has the property that when $x$ and $y$ differ by 30 bits, then $f(x) \neq f(y)$, then the bound holds; $f$ must have a different value on each string in the clique otherwise the condition is directly violated.

Comment: Can I check, if the bit arrays are of length 6 (instead of 90) does your improvement give fewer than 3 bits for the message length? I don’t think this is possible.

Comment: @Simd. No, this doesn't work for 6. Before my optimization, the method would be sending two bits of row parity information, and the two bit flips could invert both of them. This issue only seems to apply to the six case (since otherwise $n/2 -1 > n/3$). (In considering other numbers, I will point out since I haven't seen anyone mention it explicitly, that user1502040's grid method doesn't work for any multiple of 4 flips since flipping both bits in two rows isn't detected. I think it works for multiples of 2 that aren't multiples of 4.)

Comment: That's a very nice explanation, again. So what do you think you can get for 84 bits? A number larger than 42?

Comment: @Simd If the number of flips is a multiple of 4 but not 8 (like 28), I think I can see a generalization of the 2x? grid method, but it takes around 3n/4 bits instead of around n/2 bits, so not better than something like isaacg's method if the number of swaps is n/3. I'm not sure how I would get close to n/2 bits in general, but I could easily be missing something.

Comment: @newQOpenWid Splitting things up is tricky because you don't know how many errors are in each part. The grid method is like splitting things up into groups of 2, but it seems like this is mainly useful because it basically divides the number of errors by 2 to get an odd number which is easier to detect. But, to use larger groups in a similar way seems to need more information per group. For example, in a 2x2 grid, (00)(00) has the same row/column parities as (11)(11), and as a consequence 2x? grid can't detect errors in multiples of 4; but in 3x3, (110)(011)(101) is also zero (contd.)

Comment: (contd. from previous) so all even numbers of errors except 2 itself can be undetected. I can see how $n-1$ bits of message can get useful info from a group of $n$ bits, as this can detect any number of errors less than $n$, but this is quite inefficient for large groups.

Comment: hmm, I see. My plan was for Andreas to invert their bits and for both of them to get the total parity of each group of 15 (If Carroll flips 30 bits, then at least one of the groups must be completely flipped) and compare them, but I see how that fails now...

Comment: @newQOpenWid Carroll can flip any 30 bits, e.g. 10 from three groups and 0 from the other three.

Comment: By the way, we could just be very cheeky and use mod-17: that way, Carroll is forced to reveal that she flipped a bit, and we can just have 5 bits of information for each group, right?

Comment: What does it mean if the chromatic number is not a power of two? If I have 2^6 = 64 nodes and add an edge if the Hamming distance between the corresponding arrays of length 6 is exactly 4, it seems the chromatic number of the graph is 7.

Comment: @newQOpenWid In your original scheme for the misunderstood problem you only needed one bit per group. I don't know what you are taking mod 17 of, but e.g. the number of 1's mod 17 of a group of 15 doesn't make sense as that is less than 17 anyway. You could treat it as a binary number and go mod 17 I suppose, but that doesn't necessarily detect bit flips, as many numbers are the same mod 17. Mod M can be useful though, e.g. if you want to send the total number of 1 bits, you can do this mod 64 to save a bit I believe.

Comment: @Simd If you need to send a whole number of bits, then you would need to round up. But, there would be some bit patterns that you would never use. E.g. if the chromatic number of 7, you could just encode a number from 0 to 6 in binary, and you don't use 111. If you are sending more information at a time, you may be able to save a full bit. To send 6 numbers from 0 to 6, you can e.g. convert it to a 6-digit number in base 7 which will be less than 2^17, so this can be sent in 17 bits whereas it would take 3*6=18 bits to send these individually. ($6\log_2(7)<17$)

Comment: @Simd, Also, I was thinking more about 84 with 28 errors, and I think a 3x? grid method can detect find any non-multiple of 3 errors in 2n/3 (but this is still only ties the isaacg method for your parameters).

Comment: @newQOpenWid It could be that e.g. in three groups 5 1's become 0's and 5 0's become 1's. Then the number of 1's in each group hasn't changed, but there have been 30 bit flips altogether.

Comment: My original idea about modular was that we could emulate fljx's answer for the 99-bit case, but it appears that Carroll is able to circumvent any such methods. Maybe the idea should be sending a message to encode the *position* of the 0s and 1s, since 'total amount of 0s/1s' fails, but that doesn't get very far (the farthest we can get is sending 60 bits, like issacg's answer). I've also been thinking about error-correction algorithms in cryptography, but you need a massive amount of bits sent to detect a 30-bit error with those.

Comment: @newQOpenWid Another now-deleted answer tried to use a CRC and wasn't able to get it to work. If you're reducing 90 bits to ~32 or whatever, you are going to have ~2^58 or so strings mapping to the same CRC (this is not unique to CRC though). If any of the strings mapping to the same CRC differ by exactly 30 bits, then it doesn't solve the problem. In the cases that were proposed, it was very easy to find a 90 bit string with 30 1's that had CRC 0; so the desired property certainly isn't something you get automatically. I guess I'm not 100% sure that it's impossible to find a working CRC.

Comment: Out of interest, what would you get if they both have 10 bit arrays and they need to distinguish between being entirely distinct and have 2 bits in common. Does Andrei need to send 5 or only 4 bits?

Comment: @Simd: I think the method in this answer will work (detect identical vs 2 bits differ) with 4 bits.

Answer (score 11):

It is possible for them to make

> <s>\$4400</s> $4500 (<s>46</s> 45 bits used)

> First, Andrei inverts his input, so either 0 bits or 30 bits differ. Then he splits the input into a 45x2 grid, and sends the parity of each row of 2 (edit: thanks to Retudin for pointing out that the parity of the last row is redundant and can be skipped), and the parity of the first column. Belle checks if she gets the same result as Andrei on her input. For each row to have the same parity for both parties, both bits must be flipped at once (or neither flipped), but that means 15 bits in each column will be flipped, and the column parity will not match.

Comment: No need to send the last row, since the total parity does not change; this gives +100$

Comment: @Retudin Good point

Comment: I had to give the bounty to someone but your work is really good progress. I am starting another bounty

Comment: I'm late to the party, but if Andrei inverts his input, doesn't that mean 0 or 60 bits differ, not 0 or 30?

Answer (score 6):

I doubt this is optimal, but to get us started, Andrei and Belle can make

> $3000

Andrei's procedure is:

> If the first bit is a 1, invert all of the bits. Then send the next 60 bits.

Belle can reconstruct this:

> If Belle's first bit is a 1, flip all of the bits received. Then check if they match Belle's next 60 bits.

The reason this works is:

> If the first bit was flipped between Andrei and Belle, only 29 flips remain, so the next 60 will have at least 31 errors. If the first bit wasn't flipped, and 30 bits were flipped, the next 60 bits will have at least one error.

Comment: rot13(Vf gur vairefvba arrqrq? V guvax Naqerv pna whfg fraq gur svefg fvkgl-bar ovgf nf-vf, naq Oryyr pna pbzcner gurz nf-vf.)

Comment: @DanielWagner We want to send less bits. This method only sends 60 bits.

Comment: Right! My mistake.

Answer (score 4):

This is a weak lower bound showing that at least 4 bits must be sent.

We follow [tehtmi's observation](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/121647/4551) that the problem is to effectively to find the chromatic number of the graph on the $2^{90}$ binary strings of length 90 which has an edge between two strings whenever they differ by exactly 30 bit flips. We improve on their size-6 clique by finding a clique of size 14, which requires 14 colors and so means that at least $\log_2(14)$ bits of information must be sent, so at least 4.

The clique is the 14 rows below, with 0's shown as blank for clarity. You can check that any two rows differ in exactly 30 positions.

```
11111111111111111111                                             
11111               111111111111111                              
11111                              111111111111111               
11111                                             111111111111111
     11111          11111          11111          11111          
     11111               11111          11111          11111     
     11111                    11111          11111          11111
          11111     11111               11111               11111
          11111          11111               1111111111          
          11111               1111111111               11111     
               1111111111                    11111     11111     
               11111     11111     11111                    11111
               11111          11111     11111     11111          
                                                                 1111111111
```

The construction uses the projective place for $N=3$, which has $N^2+N+1=13$ points and lines:

[image: projective plane matrix]

*Image from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_plane#A_finite_example*

All rows have four 1's, and any two rows overlap in one 1, so there are 6 positions where they differ. By replacing each column with a block of 5, we scale up the difference to 30 positions, using 65 columns. We can then add a 14th row whose 1-bits occupy 10 used positions, and so also differs in 30 bits from any other row, having used total 75 columns of our allowance with 15 to spare.

Unfortunately we're just short of using the projective-plane for $N=5$, which has 31 rows and would use $31 \cdot 3= 93$ columns. This would show that for a 93-bit version of the problem, at least $\log_2(31)$ bits are needed, and so 5 at minimum. The $N=4$ plane isn't suitable either because an two rows different at 8 positions, and 30 isn't a multiple of 8.

Comment: I guess you mean a 93 bit version where you still have an edge between two strings whenever they differ by exactly 30 bit flips?

Comment: @Simd Yes, still 30 bit flips

Comment: I have no idea who to award the bounty to now! :-/

Comment: I had to give the bounty to someone but your lower bound is really good progress. I am starting another bounty

Comment: Could an algorithm that finds the largest clique possible be made?

Comment: I think you can get to 18 like this: Instead of adding the 14th point as ten new columns, you could add a new point by taking a 1 overlapping with each group of 5 plus 5 new columns. Since this has 18 1s, there can be multiple of these that are mutually adjacent. At least 5 can be added (each overlapping with a different bit from each group of 5 and all overlapping with each other in 3 of the new columns).

Comment: Here's 38: https://pastebin.com/4KP0gfnc

Comment: @tehtmi wow, nice! Does that mean that we have to send at least 6 bits? Still a weak lower bound, but expanding this is definitely possible (using the aforementioned algorithm, perhaps?)

Comment: @tehtmi Very nice, how did you construct the 38? Perhaps you can post this as an answer? Indeed this shows a 6 bit minimum.

Comment: @xnor, I edited an explanation into my answer. (Not sure how well I explained it, and I'm still trying to figure out if there is a better way to use this kind of construction, as the way it worked out here seemed very fortuitous...)

Answer (score 2):

The crc method and modulo methods didn't work (previous answers now deleted), but maybe 3rd time is the charm? I don't know how to prove / disprove it. I've done some exploratory coding.

**Step 1**: Send 5 bits with the count of the number of 1s in the number. 5?! Yes, 5 (*I originally had 6, but commenters pointed out 5 is enough*). Because 0-14 and 76-90 all just get a 0, and 15-75 get 1-61, and so I only need 0-62 or 6 bits. If there are 0-14 or 76-90 1s, then it's impossible to have a hamming distance of 30 and also have 0-14 or 76-90 1s in the string. But the parity is known, so you can save a bit.

So at the end of this, we will know that both numbers have the same number of 1s. Which means the only failure mode is 15 1s changed to 0s and 15 0s changed to 1s. Or, put another way, 15 1s moved to new spots on the string formerly occupied by 0s.

(***Update**: I've changed step 2. This was my original idea, but then I thought the modulo arithmetic idea was equivalent and easier to explain so I went with that, but commenters pointed out that it didn't work. So I reverted to this and I think it makes more sense.*)

**Step 2**: Here it gets a little more sketchy and it may be possible to further optimize. But the basic idea is to efficiently detect movement of 1s, as follows:

1. Take these 6 prime numbers: [7,13,17,19,23,29]. These numbers are chosen because they are prime and the product of any 2 is bigger than 90, and 6 choose 2 is 15.
2. For each prime, create an index $a$, such that $a[(i\cdot p)\mod 90]=i$, for $i$ running from 0 to 90, and $p$ in the above list. So for $p=7$, the index is [0, 13, 26, 39, 52, 65, 78, 1, 14, 27, 40, 53, 66, 79, 2, 15, 28, 41, 54, 67, 80, 3, 16, 29, 42, 55, 68, 81, 4, 17, 30, 43, 56, 69, 82, 5, 18, 31, 44, 57, 70, 83, 6, 19, 32, 45, 58, 71, 84, 7, 20, 33, 46, 59, 72, 85, 8, 21, 34, 47, 60, 73, 86, 9, 22, 35, 48, 61, 74, 87, 10, 23, 36, 49, 62, 75, 88, 11, 24, 37, 50, 63, 76, 89, 12, 25, 38, 51, 64, 77].
3. Take the dot product of our binary string with the index mod $p$ for each $p$.
4. So if my binary were $[1,1,0,\ldots,0]$ (just two 1s), the remainders would be $(6, 7, 2, 0, 1, 1)$.
5. Encode these remainders into $7\times13\times\ldots\times29$ numbers and encode as 25 bits.
6. If all these remainders are the same, then you can assume that the numbers haven't moved.

I actually suspect that step 2 may work without step 1.

> So a total of $25 + 5 = 30$ bits. My program is still running, but it won't finish in my life time with the current hardware. Or, if we don't need step 1, then $25$ bits will be enough.

So the above is a tentative answer, until I can justify it or find a counter-example, or (more likely) someone here figures out what I did wrong...

---

Hands-wavey argument that this is better than the original method. If you wanted to detect the movement of a 1 in a string of length 6, you could clearly do it with primes $[2,3]$ using this method. But using the old method, any strings that differed by 6 would return the same hash.

---

**Coding update**:

I'm looking at the worst-case scenario, which is 45 1s out of 90. I'm moving 15 1s from the original set into new locations. So far, I've checked 1,000,000 such moves, and have had 0 failures in the original divisor set [7,13,17,19,23,29] and the index formed by $a[(i*p)\mod90]=i$.

Comment: Wouldn't this fail to catch two flips with 30 empty spaces in between them, because that's the XOR of the 31-ones polynomial with itself shifted by 1, and so divisible is by it? You might need the polynomial to have further properties.

Comment: I've actually been running my program with 1000000000000001000000000000001. But I'm not sure it makes a difference. What's the example that you think would fail? I'm not sure I follow you.

Comment: For example with 1000000000000001000000000000001, 0...0 has the the same crc, 0, as 0...01111111111000001111111111000001111111111, obviously just 1111111111 times your polynomial, so also remainder 0. And, this differs by exactly 30 bits.

Comment: For polynomial of 1111111111111111111111111111111, 0...01111111111111110000000000000000111111111111111 is an example with crc 0 and hamming weight 30.

Comment: Failures for a crc of 31 ones: [TIO](https://tio.run/##hVPBboMwDL3zFR4XSMdQWdVpqtRT/2BXVqEAoWRKExSC1n49i0lLS8e0XOI49nt@dtKcTa3k6r3RfV@yCgpdZJodKZcl0yGXTWeynJvWaC4PETRKnKU6ciruvVxyg66KC8E02Xhgl@/7OyqKTlDDwNQMdh87GKFBVUDBAaCNaNC1eKJQ1Kpl8o4sHhCnNNDWqhMl5AyCJAClIVgG8ZV62Oeqhe2sOxa4N6HFIEOuYDIb5NsEaz@2gkwqamhZOuwQY@cICLxAQmDxoOICg9gIwsqMak3PSMpb88gKz4@Uro7vmgvXBi5n0NLNqGbvhoOr6HTW1rxChb9zYhzTKbSYZMyobJM5UmgqD@xvqeRGMi8vvXFbRXv4nMRv8V1Y6WYWPbXxT9v/QYmrWzPTaQlBEH8pfh3jfRpJx@Zs9r19/5bfT/zFKvE8ivbS2q9e7twWenAs0Uh87xJt55qs3R2ab@4WFsna87BrJ@xaSqM8Ki4TaDQKnH63U2TPkcUgpP8B)

Comment: Counterexample for product of first 10 primes: 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011011000001010010000001010110010010010010 and 110110000010100100000010101100100100100100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000. By Chinese Remainder Theorem, remainder mod each prime is equivalent info to remainder mod product of them. I looked for a multiple of the modulus with 15 1's, then shift it over (multiply by power of 2, still divisible by all those primes) to get another multiple that differs by 30 bits and both have 15 1's. Counterexample doesn't have to have this form though.

Comment: Also, if you want to send the number of 1's, I think you can save another bit because you know the parity of the number of 1's is the same for Andrei and Belle.

Comment: Those are both clever points. So you saved us a bit in step 1 and totally destroyed step 2. Good old Chinese Remainder theorem. I should have thought of that. So for the CRT not to destroy the method, we would need the product to be greater than about 2^90 and so the whole thing falls apart, right?

Comment: This method of producing a counterexample may start to break earlier, as I needed to fit a (hopefully small) multiple of the modulus together with a non-overlapping shift of itself, so the multiple of the modulus couldn't be too much bigger than 2^45 without some extra finesse. Of course, modulus of 2^45 won't beat the current best answer, and I'm doubtful a smaller modulus would work, though there may be a small window where a different kind of counterexample is needed. (Not sure >2^45 works either, but may be harder to find a counterexample.)

Comment: Do you think we could send a bit for whether it's a multiple of the product of first primes and adapt

Comment: I don't think the only collisions will be multiples of the modulus. For example, if you add the same thing to both numbers, their remainders will still be equal, so if you can do this without changing the number of 1's between the two numbers (many ways to do these including but not limited to adding numbers that won't carry), it will still be a counterexample.

Comment: I updated it with a better method. I think.

Comment: Operation is the same as taking dot product with [0, 1, 2, 3, ..., 89] (assuming you start with 0, but example with [3, 3, ...] seems to imply starting with 1; but I don't think it matters substantively) then mod p at the end. But, I think there is a collision even if you don't mod p. Just need two disjoint 15-element subsets of {0, ..., 89} with the same sum (not to hard to find by hand): 000000000000000000000000000001000100000000000000000000000000000001100110011001100110011001 and 000000000000000000000000000000011000000000000000000000000000000010011001100110011001100110

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147492/discussion-between-dr-xorile-and-tehtmi).

Comment: Didn't read any further yet, but 4 bits is enough to communicate the number of 1s: A can send the number of 1s, divided by 2 (rounded down), modulo 16. B can count the corresponding number for their zeroes, and get the same result if and only if the number is the same: parity prevents any odd number of changes (so the division hides nothing), and there being no more than 30 changes prevents the mod16 from looping back to the correct number. If B gets a different number than A, B won't get to know A's number, but instead of caring, they instantly win.

Comment: Great point. I almost got there with my initial thoughts on the 0-14 and 76-90. Now if we can just make the hash function work. See discussion page

Comment: Wait. If A has 16 1s and Binv has 32, and they have an overlap of 9, then isn't their hamming distance 30? And they still have the same score mod 16.

Comment: @DrXorile: Divided by 2 modulo 16 (sending 8 vs 0), or modulo 32 and don't send the 1's digit (sending 16 vs 0).

Comment: @DrXorile halve first, mod16 after.

Comment: Ah, yes. Okay. That's cool.

Answer (score -2):

FWIW - this is my first post on PSE. Bear with me. ;)

This puzzle has been discussed long enough that there doesn't appear to be any value in using spoilers, so here goes.

It seems like it should be possible to get $7100 by expanding on User1502040's approach, but instead of using a 2x45 grid, use a 9x10 grid and send an array of the parity bits for each row and column (19 bits total).

After Andrei inverts his string and builds his grid, there are two (or maybe three) possibilities:

1. Some parity bits differ from the transmitted string, so the 30 bits must have been inverted.
2. The 30 bits were not inverted, so both strings of parity bits are exactly the same.
3. And maybe - the 30 bits were inverted, but the parity bit strings are still the same.

So the question is - is option #3 possible? If not, then that leaves only #1 or #2.

Clearly, any given row or column maintains its parity if an even number of bits are inverted (multiples of 2). The trick is - is there a sequence of bits that could result in inverting an even number of bits in all rows AND all columns? If the number of bits in question is divisible by 4, this is trivial (think a 2x2 grid within the larger grid, or 4 corners of a larger square).

But having 30 bits in question leaves 2 extra bits after you pair up the row & column groups of 4. So there will be one row (or column) with 2 inverted bits that span two columns (or rows) without an offsetting inversion. So these two columns (or rows) will change their parity bits. Therefore, option #3 is not possible, so there is a clear indicator of option #1 vs. option #2.

Is this optimal? I don't know in general, but for this grid based approach it's clearly optimal since 9x10 is as close as you can get to a square grid.

Comment: As you said, you can flip 4 bits in a square (11)(11) and go undetected. You can also flip 6 bits in a pattern like this (110)(101)(011). If you combine these, you can get 30 undetected flips. Doesn't affect the existing answer because the 6 bit flip requires at least 3 rows/columns.

Comment: Oops. I knew this was too simple to have been missed by the folks on PSE. ;)